# Copying data in a simple vector class

Tags: c++, templates, vector, dynamic

I'm trying write my own vector class:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int default_size = 2) :
        size(0), data_member(new T[default_size]), capacity(default_size) {};

    Vector(const Vector& obj)
    {
        data_member = new T[obj.size];
        data_member = obj.data_member;
        size = obj.size;
        capacity = obj.capacity;
    }

    void push_back(T& elem)
    {
        if (size == capacity)
            resize(2 * size);
        data_member[size] = elem;
        size++;

    }

    void push_front(T& data)
    {
        if (size + 1 == capacity)
            resize(2 * size);
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            data_member[i + 1] = data_member[i];
        }
        data_member[0] = data;
        size++;
    }

    void pop_back()
    {
        --size;
    }

    void resize(int size_)
    {
        if (size_ > capacity)
        {
            T* temp = new T[size_];
            memcpy(temp, data_member, size * sizeof(T));
            delete[] data_member;
            data_member = new T[size_];
            data_member = temp;
            //delete[] temp;
            capacity = size_;
        }
    }

    int get_size() { return size; }

    T* getarr() { return data_member; }

private:
    T* data_member;
    int size;
    int capacity;

};
```

and here is a main for testing my class

```
int main()
{
    Vector<int> myint;
    int a = 5, b = 8, c = 9;
    myint.push_back(a);
    myint.push_back(b);
    myint.push_back(c);
    Vector<int> you = myint;
    int* arr1 = you.getarr();
    for (int i = 0; i < you.get_size(); i++)
    {
        cout << *arr1 << endl;
        arr1++;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    int h[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    int* hp = h;
    int g[3] = { 4,5,6 };
    int* gp = g;
    int f[3] = { 4,5,6 };
    int* fp = f;
    Vector<int*> myarrint;
    myarrint.push_back(hp);
    myarrint.push_back(gp);
    myarrint.push_back(fp);
    int** arr = myarrint.getarr();
    for (int i = 0; i < myarrint.get_size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << **arr << endl;
            (*arr)++;
        }
        arr++;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    Vector<string> mystr;
    string s1 = "I";
    string s2 = "went";
    string s3 = "shopping";
    mystr.push_back(s1);
    mystr.push_back(s2);
    mystr.push_back(s3);
    string* str1 = mystr.getarr();
    for (int i = 0; i < mystr.get_size(); i++)
    {
        cout << *str1 << endl;
        str1++;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    string i = "wow";
    mystr.push_front(i);
    string* str2 = mystr.getarr();
    for (int i = 0; i < mystr.get_size(); i++)
    {
        cout << *str2 << endl;
        str2++;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new in c++ and I'm really confused, I think in my `push_back` function, I'm just making my objects point to `temp` and I'm not copying temp in them , so if I want to delete temp in the end of my `push_back` function my `data_member`s will be lost. So what is the right way to do so?

second if I want to make a dynamic array of `string`s my program will crash sometimes, and I think ,it's because of `memcpy()` in my `resize` function, still I don't know what should I do instead of it?

Comment: There is a memory leak in `resize()`: `data_member = new T[size_];` directly followed by `data_member = temp;`. This copies the _pointer_ from `temp` to `data_member` and the previous allocation gets immediately lost (not accessible anymore but still existing). And, of course, the commented `delete[] temp;` would be fatal because `data_member` (pointing now to the same memory) would become dangling due to this.

Comment: `memcpy(temp, data_member, size * sizeof(T));` -- This will not work correctly for non-POD types.  If you had `Vector<std::string>` you will see this will not work.  The correct function to use is `std::copy`.

Comment: In addition, your copy constructor is broken, as it only makes shallow copies.  You also forgot the assignment operator and destructor.  Advice -- if you're going to write your own vector class, the minimum you *must* have coded are the copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor, complete, full, and well-tested.  If you don't have those three functions, you can't write any tests.  Once you have those functions, then proceed with the functions to add, remove, etc. items from the vector.

Comment: I forgot that you also need to have the constructor to allocate memory (which you have now).  So you need 4 functions, not just the 3 I mentioned.  Then you should test creating, copying, assigning, destructor, etc. to make sure the class has correct copy semantics.  Once that is well-tested, then write the other functions to complete the vector class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right I will add destructor to it, but I'm very new in c++ and I haven't learned about operators yet.I was asked to write a very simple class  like vector class which can basically add data and delete it(in different position).though I will be really thankful ,if you help me with copy constructor.

Comment: I could show you a complete vector class, but can't do that if this is your assignment.  The copy constructor's job is to make self-contained copy of the passed-in object.  You need to allocate the array just like in the other constructor, copy the data over from the old object to the new object.  You didn't do that, you only assigned pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually I'm really confused about copying part, I'm allocating memory but I don't know how to copy data instead of just make pointer, point to to object .which is my problem also in `push_back` function , when I'm copying 'temp` in `data_member`.can you give any clue how to do that?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is there any alternative to `std::copy` to copy my string in temp?

Comment: A regular `for` loop, copying one-by-one.